# Excel VBA Passing String Variable for use in Range Filter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to replace a series of Excel VBA scripts that use 'literal' references...

```
Sub OrdenBetel()
'
' OrdenBetel Macro
' Macro recorded 7/14/2006 by
'
    Sheets("Master PO CA").Select
    Sheets("Master PO CA").Copy After:=Sheets(3)
    Sheets("Requerimientos CA").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Betel International"
    Range("C7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("A5:S400").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Master PO CA (2)").Select
    Range("A12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
         False, Transpose:=False
    Rows("12:12").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Requerimientos CA").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1
    Range("C7").Select
    Sheets("Master PO CA (2)").Select
    Sheets("Master PO CA (2)").Name = "PO Betel International"
    Sheets("PO Betel International").Select
    Sheets("PO Betel International").Move
'
End Sub
```

... with a single VBA script that accepts a string parameter:

```
Dim Vendor_Name As String 'in the General Declarations section

Sub PO_Create(Vendor_Name)
'
'

    Sheets("Master PO CA").Select
    Sheets("Master PO CA").Copy After:=Sheets(3)
    Sheets("Requerimientos CA").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Vendor_Name
    Range("C7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("A5:S400").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Master PO CA (2)").Select
    Range("A12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
         False, Transpose:=False
    Rows("12:12").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Requerimientos CA").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1
    Range("C7").Select
    Sheets("Master PO CA (2)").Select
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = Vendor_Name
    Sheets(Vendor_Name).Select
    Sheets(Vendor_Name).Move

'
End Sub
```

I'm calling PO_Create from a Worksheet_Change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Application.Range("PO_Create_Range")) _
        Is Nothing Then

        Vendor_Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value

        PO_Create (Vendor_Name)

    End If

End Sub
```

...but as far as I can tell nothing is being passed to PO_Create. The AutoFilter doesn't find anything (even though there are definitely values in the range) and the new Worksheet is being assigned a generic number instead of the Vendor_Name.

Comment: Have you tried to debug line-by-line? Put up a 'stop' in the line of code "If IsEmpty..." by click the left border in the VBA window next to that line. Then run the macro - when it gets to that line it will stop. Then press F8 and it will run the code one line at a time. Hover over the variables - do you see values you didn't expect? Confirm the string Vendor_Name. Is that a character-for-character match for one of your sheetnames?

Comment: Thank-you, Grade Eh. I'll do exactly that. If someone asked me for help with SQL (my normal environment) I'd have suggested much the same thing. Somehow when I try to do something in an unfamiliar language all of my common sense goes out the window. :p I'll let you know how I make out...

Comment: :) It was the simplest/stupidest mistake possible. I was grabbing the wrong cell value in my ActiveCell.Offset because I hadn't noticed there was a hidden column between the current cell and the value I was looking for. Thanks again, Grade 'Eh'!

Comment: Great, happy that worked out for you. Alternatively - in VBA, you can type STOP as a single line of code which does the same thing. So if you have a loop of 10k items but want to see the values at 4567, type If i = 4567 Then STOP